# Showing a Map is Open

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ and $g: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ be continuously differentiable such that $f', D_1g, D_2g$ are never $0$. Define $h(x,y,z)$ by $(f(x)+g(y,z), f(y)-g(x,z))$. Show that $h$ is an open map.

The only way we have been shown to do this is use a corollary to the Inverse Function Theorem: If $f$ is a $C'$ mapping of an open subset $E \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ to $\mathbb{R}^n$ and if $f'(x)$ is invertible for all $x \in E$, then $f(W)$ is oppen for all open $W \subset E$.

While it is clear that $h$ is continuously differentiable, $h$ is not a map $\mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}^3$. Clearly, $h$ has Jacobian
$$
Jh=
\begin{pmatrix}
f' & D_1g & D_2g \\
-D_1g & f' & -D_2g
\end{pmatrix}
$$
This is not a square matrix so it cannot be invertible. While we can think of $\mathbb{R}^2$ as a subset of $\mathbb{R}^3$ this only adds a zero row to the Jacobian so this does not help with invertibility. What have I missed to be able to answer this question?